# Django ORM access optimization with Filter

Tags: python, django, orm

I've implemented a method on my django app that will check if a user has a specific permission or it's part of a group that contains this specific permission.

```
def user_has_perm(user, *permissions_to_check):
        permission_check = True
        permissions_not_found = []

        user_groups = user.groups.all().prefetch_related('permissions')

        for permission in permissions_to_check:
            content_type, permission_codename = permission.split('.')
            if not user.has_perm(permission) and not user_groups.filter(
                    permissions__content_type__model__icontains=content_type,
                    permissions__codename__icontains=permission_codename).exists():  # Goes down from Groups to the single user permission
                permission_check = False
                permissions_not_found.append(permission)

        return permission_check, permissions_not_found
```

Now, everythings works like a charm, but, Django-Debug-Toolbar it's complaining about the query, that it's duplicated many times as the groups to check.

For me it's a bottleneck, because some users will have 50 groups associated, and really i don't know how to optimize this query...

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Permission checking can be expensive. It could be a good idea to retrieve all permissions of a user on login and cache them for some time.

Comment: There are some different alternatives?

Comment: It's really so difficult?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Klaus, this is a database killer. If there lots of permissions (even without any apps of your own, there will be quite a few), you could potentially find yourself executing hundreds of queries in your `user_has_perm` function. You could reduce that with caching

```
from django.core.cache import cache.

def user_has_perm(user, *permissions_to_check):
    hash = # create a hash from user.id and permissions_to_check.
           # maybe something as simple as "".join(permissions_to_check)

    perms = cache.get(hash)
    if perms: 
         return perms

    permission_check = True
    permissions_not_found = []

    user_groups = user.groups.all().prefetch_related('permissions')

    for permission in permissions_to_check:
        content_type, permission_codename = permission.split('.')
        if not user.has_perm(permission) and not user_groups.filter(
                permissions__content_type__model__icontains=content_type,
                permissions__codename__icontains=permission_codename).exists():  # Goes down from Groups to the single user permission
            permission_check = False
            permissions_not_found.append(permission)

    cache.set(hash, [permisson_check, permissions_not_found], 10**5)
    return permission_check, permissions_not_found
```

Comment: And what about the caching time? it's 5 minutes, if i want to set it to expire on user logout?

Comment: the timeout parameter is something that you can control (third param)

Comment: Can you suggest me how to control it in base of user login status?

Comment: see the edit, but you should really look at the documentation for this sort of thing.

Comment: It's a weird solution, maybe a better approach can be: 
`hash = "{0}{1}".format(request.session.session_key, permissions_to_check)`, in fact, the session_key (if i'm not wrong), it will change from login, logout status end vice-versa, right?

Comment: If you read the answer again, you will see that I have left you to come up with a hash that you think is best.